# How to optimize this database and this query?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a simple blog site where there are blogposts, users and comments.
In homepage will be shown the blogposts and below users's comments with users's information:

I have created 3 mysql table: blogpost, user, comment
and in homepage I need to do a JOIN query with these 3 tables.

Is there a way to avoid this JOIN with 3 query ?

Comment: I would split the query in two separate queries; first get the blogpost ... then get the user and comments for that blogpost.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to avoid with the JOIN?  Basically there is no way with a properly normalized database schema to avoid the JOIN (or multiple SELECTs), the only way would be to denormalize the data.  But doing this has costs, so if you tell us what your reasoning is perhaps people here can help in another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view that represents data of that 3 tables and simply select the data from that view.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-view.html)

Example:

```
create view v as 
    select t1.id, t2.id as id2 
    from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id;

select * from v;
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid the join, it merely hides it.

Comment: Yes. I think that is what the OP wants.